# How to make 4-20mA Sink Generator to Simulate with PLC or other 4-20mA Instruments?

Tags: generator, source, 4-20ma, schematic

I want to test Pressure Transmitters without actually pressure available in LAB. So I want to make 4-20ma Simulator.

I changed my Title to 4-20mA Sink Generator. As I am referring to 2 Wire Transmitter System.

I want to design Sink generator like this with Digital Display.

So switching the Transistor on/off with some fixed PWM Frequency and measuring current accurately using the INA219 module will do?

[image]

Comment: Falstad’s web simulator can do this, in slow-mo or real-time if you can design it.

Comment: *I have tried to make 4-20mA Current Simulator using Variable Buck converter* Show the schematic. Why a buck converter? For 20 mA it does not make much sense to be using a buck converter, a simple linear circuit is usually a better solution. For 100 mA or more , I would consider a buck converter in battery-fed applications.

Comment: Um, what is a "simulator" about this? You need a constant voltage source as power supply, you need your current sensing element (which can be as easy as measuring the voltage across a resistor) and you need your variable resistor. That's a current loop. Nothing simulated here!

Comment: I have PLC program to check pressure input. Now I don't have pressure line. So I need to use 4-20mA Current Source simulator to give signal (4-20mA) for program simulation.

Comment: "*I have tried to make 4-20mA Current Simulator ...*" Do you mean that you have tried to "make a generator to simulate" as suggested in your title? If so, then please [edit] to fix.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You want to make a transmitter simulator. A constant current source or sink is not too hard to make, and you'll want an accurate milliammeter. A practical device would have quick setting to 4mA/12mA/20mA  and maybe a few others. Two wire or four wire, battery or mains powered, are choices to make. Accuracy? is +/-0.1% adequate? Stability?

Comment: I want to make 2 Wire 4-20mA Simulator to test without Actual Transducer. Main problem Is i doubt simulator need same 24V or 0-10V for 4-20mA ?

Comment: *I want to test Pressure Transmitters without actually pressure available in LAB* - not going to happen. And, what this has got to do with building a 4/20 mA transmitter is unresolved. What has the picture of a DVM got to do with the question?

Comment: Using PWM is not really a good idea since you don't know the time constants of the receiver. *Every* 4-20mA transmitter is linear (and many use the BC56 part). If you are lazy just buy a dedicated IC, they are not expensive these days. Otherwise use an opamp sink boosted with a transistor of your choice

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi26sS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple analog circuit.*

Many 4 - 20 mA inputs have a 250 Ω shunt resistor to convert 20 mA to 5 V. If this is what you are dealing with then you can simulate the transmitters with a PP3 style 9 V battery, a potentiometer, a limiting resistor and a multimeter in mA mode. It's very cheap and should suffice for testing.

- With R1 wiper at bottom the current will be 9 / (2k + 200 + 250) = 3.7 mA.
- With R1 wiper at top the current will be 9 / (200 + 250) = 20 mA.

Decrease R2 to 180 Ω to allow a little more current to ensure that you can reach 20 mA with a deteriorating battery.

Comment: Okay now i understand this is 4-20mA Source Generator for 4 Wire Transmitters. I need 4-20mA Sink Circuit. Because I am already having 24V power available from PLC to drive the Transducer. In place of transducer i will use Sink Simulator to change current value from 4-20mA.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is very confused. Please provide a link to the datasheet of the device under test. It might help to also include a link to the datasheet of the missing transducer.

Comment: And if the device resistance isn't 250 ohms?

Comment: Yes, this is how people did it in the old days. Before I got my degree, I built a few of these for the lab. It had a small linear power supply instead of a battery.

Comment: "*And if the device resistance isn't 250 ohms?*" I have shown the calculations in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I have done this correctly (you need to check, don't rely on strangers to design your circuits), this should do what you want.

The XTR117 chip is powered by the current loop line, and regulates the current in the loop. The loop current is 100x that at the "IN" terminal. There is 5V between terminals 8 and 2, so, if I have calculated correctly, the current in the loop will lie between 4 mA and 20 mA based upon the setting of R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGb207.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for idea. will make 4-20mA Simulator using this.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting answers for your questions.